# What is the typical command structure and number of officers on a Galaxy-class starship?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

We have only seen the main crew of TNG as the high ranking officers aboard the USS Enterprise D. MY questions are:

1. In a ship with over 1000 personnel and families, can we assume that they are the only high ranking officers on board or that there are others but not shown for story telling reasons.
2. If no other high ranking officers are aboard, what would happen to the command structure (hierarchy) if the bridge crew was lost (especially that they all go on away missions which could be dangerous), who would take control of the Enterprise D?
3. We have seen Engineering, Medical and Security with high ranking officers, are there any other departments with high officers which we know of.

Comment: Okay, I won't vote to close this one, but it is too many questions and relationships to even try to answer effectively. Rank structures and relationships, relationships in command structure, who is in charge under what conditions, departments on board ship, and since we have only seen the crew of one Galaxy-class starship, we can't presume to guess every configuration of ship complement. And while we are at it, which Enterprise, D or E?

Comment: Also, there's the question of formality/informality - we saw the structure (more social than official, I suppose) change in one episode due to an admiral taking command of the Enterprise during TNG and being much more rigid than Picard...

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to figure out if there is a Civillian hierarchy, because the basic rank structure of Starfleet follows the terestrial Navy/Coast Guard rank structure

Comment: I know that. But what if the bridge crew died, who will take command on the spot. For this is the only reference to the command crew I found.
**Commanding Officer**
Captain Jean-Luc Picard
**First Officer/Executive Officer**
Commander William T. Riker
**Second Officer/Operations Officer/Science Officer**
Lieutenant Commander Data
**Chief Engineer**
Lieutenant Commander Geordi La Forge
**Tactical Officer/Security chief**
Lieutenant Daniels
Lieutenant Commander Worf
**Chief Medical Officer**
Commander Beverly Crusher
**Counselor**
Commander Deanna Troi
**Conn**
Lieutenant Hawk
Lieutenant Branson

Comment: It would simply follow rank seniority in the Command Division aboard Enterprise.

Comment: OK. That we know. But what is the typical compliment in general. Like how many officers of each rank would typically serve on a ship of this size. Are there any guidelines?

Comment: Also, what would be considered a "high-rank"?

Comment: Downvoting for one very obvious reason: This is not one question, this is three questions.  Three interesting questions I will grant you, but three questions that should be asked separately, not jammed together into one "mega question".  Especially since question 2 depends upon question 1 being answered in a certain way first.

Comment: @TheByzantine - awesome question but it would require a very long and detailed answer. To answer the question regarding the bridge crew dying, there are references to a secondary bridge crew that took over at night while the senior officers slept or what-not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This site](http://www.kitsune.addr.com/SF-Conversions/Rifts-Trek-Ships/Federation_USS_Galaxy_Cruiser.htm) lists a Galaxy-class ship as having 185 officers and 575 enlisted crew and 252 civilians (families).

Comment: That site is somebody's made-up stats for an RPG, and it has some completely wrong specs (like a forward-firing torpedo tube on the saucer section, among others).